# Custom Button that add to cart and automatically redirect to checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I'd like to create a custom button on a product page that needs to add automatically the product i'm on into the cart and send you with that product details to the checkout page.

**What i've tried so far** :

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
```

That doesnt send you on the checkout if you dont have at least 1 product in cart.

```
function add_to_cart_checkout_redirect() {
    wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( get_option( 'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) ) );
    die();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',  'add_to_cart_checkout_redirect', 11 );
```

Also doesnt work.

**Question:**

Can be done?
Am i wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want user redirect to checkout page then add this code into your function.php file

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {

    $url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
    // $url = wc_get_checkout_url(); // since WC 2.5.0

    return $url;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

Hope it will solve your query .

Comment: You didnt understood. I want to be redirected to the checkout, not the cart after pressing on "add to cart" btn. It's functionality be like: Click on a button, add in background to the cart, when the item is in cart, redirect the user to checkout.

Comment: I have updated the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

if you can check this way may be help

```
$product = get_product($id);
echo "<a href='" . $product->add_to_cart_url() ."'>add to cart</a>";
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Doesnt do anything in my case.